# Get the full value of a style attribute containing invalid css

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I am trying to get the string value of a style attribute in a HTML element. The problem I am facing is that if a style property has an invalid value the property is omitted from the result.

Example:

```
<article id="Contact" style="margin: 10px; padding: 10px; color:{Color};">
</article>

var contact =  document.getElementById("Contact");
var style = contact.getAttribute("style");
console.log(style); //Prints "margin: 10px; padding: 10px;"
```

I want it to print *"margin: 10px; padding: 10px; color:{Color};"*

https://jsfiddle.net/wybdL7xk/2/

Is there anyway I can get the whole value in Internet Explorer?

*Chrome works as pointed below

Comment: What browser are you using? It works in Chrome 43.

Comment: Internet Explorer 11

Comment: This looks to be browser implementation specific.

Comment: The problem here is that IE removes the invalid CSS from the DOM when it loads... So I'm afraid there is no way to retrieve it. Open IE and take a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7bhbogg1/) to see what I mean. You could use a `data-style` attribute to store that string, though. [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/v9x62jyv/)

Comment: I see.. thank you. That can be a good feature or a bad one depending on the situation. If anyone figures out a way around it even though it seems that there is nothing that can be done about it please post it.

Comment: It seems to work in literally every browser except IE (Even MS Edge has it working). Any reason why it needs to be IE? Also, can you change what gets built in that style?

Comment: That is my main browser and I wanted it to work on every browser. I worked around it by using data-style.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use an AJAX request to read CSS document. This way you are not getting children of the DOM, but rather a text file.

```
 $.when($.get("document.css")).done(function(response){
       console.log(response);
       // Do something with response text
 }):
```